# Error de peticion JSON CORS REACT

Tags: reactjs, fetch, async

```
getWeather= async e =>{
  e.preventDefault()

  const {city,country}=e.target.elements
  const cityValue=city.value
  const countryValue=country.value
  const API_URL = `https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityValue},${countryValue}&appid=${WEATHER_KEY}`
  const response = await fetch(API_URL);
  const data = response.json()
}
```

NO puedo traer un servicio me da un error por consola de los CORS

Comment: me da error por consola de:  has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: eso casi siempre es error del servidor que no acepta conexiones de productos cruzados